# Holiday Formatting Dilemma

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, seasonal

Can you find a way to reformat the following scroogy message into a more appropriate holiday sentiment?

[image]

Hint:

> [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle) means (in this instance): [word-search](/questions/tagged/word-search)
>
>  Start at the star.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that

> cutting out most of the message would significantly improve it:
>
>  [image]
>
>  In the shape of a Christmas tree (with a star at the top), we see the message MERRY CHRISTMAS T' YOU.
>
>  (It seems like an O should be included, but the only two nearby seem too far away or not part of the tree.)

Comment: That makes me feel better about the holidays. Nice! The "O" in question is to the right of the "T" at the bottom-right of the branch structure. It's slightly off-kilter, but, gee whilakers! These were hard to place...